# Using d3 with Bootstrap 4 React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a webpage that has multiple d3 charts that stack down the middle of the page. I'm using Bootstrap4React for this, which basically works the same as the Bootstrap grid system, but instead of aligning centrally down the page, the components seem to completely ignore the rows and columns.

```
render = () => {
return (
  <Container fluid>
    <Row>
      <Col col="col lg-auto">
        <BarChartScaled
          data={this.state.data}
          width={this.state.width}
          height={this.state.height}
          id={this.state.id}
          color="red"
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>

    <Row>
      <Col col="col lg-auto">
        <BarChart
          data={this.state.data}
          width={this.state.width}
          height={this.state.height}
          id={this.state.id}
          color="green"
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
);
};
```

One of the components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";

class BarChart extends Component {
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.drawChart();
}

drawChart = () => {
    const {data, width, height, color, id} = this.props;
    const barspace = width / data.length;
    const barWidth =  barspace * 0.9;

    const svg = d3.select('#' + id)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("style", "outline: thin solid black;")
        .style("margin-left", 0)
        
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => i * barspace)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => height - (15 * d))
        .attr("width", barWidth)
        .attr("height", (d, i) => d * 15)
        .attr("fill", color);

    svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text((d) => d)
        .attr("x", (d, i) => (i * barspace) + 5)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => height - (15 * d) - 3);
}

render = () => { 
    return (
        <div id={this.props.id}></div>
    );
}
}

export default BarChart;
```

It doesn't seem like it should be complicated, but I'm pretty stuck! Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the code reproduced somewhere?

Comment: No, it's a very simple site at the moment, just trying to get the hang of React and d3 working together.

Comment: It's probably not related to d3 at all, try just replacing the `svg`s with `div`s, the problem will most likely persist